# How to find average in Reactjs when fetch from external api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to calculate average in Reactjs when data is fetched externally?

Fetching data from  - https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students

```
{api.map(student => (
    <div className="card m-3" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
      <div className="card-body">
        <img
          src={student.pic}
          alt="Student Detail"
          className="float-left rounded mx-auto d-block"
        />
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col text-left">
            <h5 className="card-title card-text">
              {student.firstName} {student.lastName}
            </h5>
            <p className="card-text"> Email: {student.email}</p>
            <p className="card-text">Company: {student.company}</p>
            <p className="card-text">Skill: {student.skills}</p>
```

I want to calculate the average inside the `<p>` tag. Note: Below is the continued code.

```
<p className="card-text">Average: {student.grades}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
```

Comment: Do `<p className="card-text">Average: {student.grades.reduce( ( p, c ) => p + c, 0 ) / student.grades.length}</p>`

Comment: Not Working @AlexShtromberg

Comment: What is `api` ?

Comment: @Titus I am passing the "api" from the parent  component as a props

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just exposed the api and this logic doesn't belong in UI but ok.

```
{student.grades.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b), 0) / student.grades.length}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create function that returns average from the array:

```
getAverage(grades){
    for( var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++ ){
        sum += parseInt( grades[i], 10 ); 
    }
    var avg = sum/grades.length;
    return avg;
}
```

and call it where you display average:

```
<p className="card-text">Average: {this.getAverage(student.grades)}</p>
```